# Add more input fields when user press button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in jquery i need some help. I have modal where user enters the title. when user enters the title  new div will be display that div contains one input filed or one addmore button when user click on addmore button new input fields will be open. I want user add upto 18 more fileds after user shows the alert message.
[image]

Here is my html code:-

```
enter code here
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add Category</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h4>Enter Your Title</h4>
            <input type="text" name="title" class="getvalue">
            <button type="submit"  class="submitdata"> Submit</button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

And My Jquery code

```
enter code here
$(document).ready(function() {
    var room= 1;
    $(".submitdata").on('click',function(){
        var value= $(".getvalue").val();
        $(".submitdata").attr('disabled');
        $(".modal-body").after(
            '<br><center><div id="contain"> 
            Choose Your Own service <br> <br>
            <input type="text" name='+value+'[]>
            <button type="button" class="addService">Add More</button>
            </div></center>'
            );
        $(".addService").on('click',function(){
              //Please anyone do coding here
        });
    });
```

Thanks ina davance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

HTML

```
<div id="contain"> 
  Choose Your Own service <br> <br>
  <div>
  <input type="text" name='+value+'[]>
  <button type="button" class="addService">Add More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('click', '.addService', function(){
    var html = '<div><input type="text" name="myInput"><button type="button" class="addService">Add More</button></div>';
  $(this).parent().append(html);
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66bw5u4h/1/)

Comment: Mayank thank you for reaply the js you have added is working fine i want Remove button instead of add button. Can you please write code for that

Comment: Thank you working fine. One thing left i want user can't add more that 5 inputs Can you please update your fiddle again. Thanks once again

Comment: Mayank ceck your fiddle firstly add 5 input fields and remove all the created fields and then try adding new fileds its gives me alert you canno add more

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.submitdata').on('click',function(){
      $(this).before($(this).closest('.getvalue').clone());
      $(this).closest('.getvalue').val('');
})
```